# Problem: 'Image has contents that are not what they are reported to be'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am getting the following error while using the paperclip GEM.I have tried uploading JPG/PNG and neither works. It seems like I am getting validation error.

> has contents that are not what they are reported to be

iinstall file.exe and add

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin'
```

to devlopement.rb

my pic.rb

```
class Pic < ActiveRecord::Base  belongs_to :user

    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/ end
```

my show.html.haml

```
= image_tag @pic.image.url
%h1= @pic.title
%p= @pic.description
%p
Pic by 
= @pic.user.try(:email)

%br

= link_to "Back", root_path
= link_to "Edit", edit_pic_path
= link_to "Delete", pic_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probléme solve update gem paperclip from 4.2.0 to 5.0.0
and run bundle install